# HTML to PDF file creator in PHP [Hindi]

Tags: php, pdf

Which is the best Html to PDF Creator in PHP with **Hindi** Font?

I tried tcpdf,mpdf,fpdf they don't have Hindi Fonts.

Any other?

Answer (score 0):

The latest TCPDF version automatically convert fonts into TCPDF format using the addTTFfont() method. For example:

```
// convert TTF font to TCPDF format and store it on the fonts folder
$fontname = TCPDF_FONTS::addTTFfont('/path-to-font/FreeSerifItalic.ttf', 'TrueTypeUnicode', '', 96);

// use the font
$pdf->SetFont($fontname, '', 14, '', false);
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally after lots of struggle I have figured out **MPDF works best for Hindi**